# How to add new classes for the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Child component

```
const Child = ({newClasses, children}) => {
      return ( 
        <div className = {`${basicClass} ${newClasses}`}>     
          {children} 
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Child
```

Parent Component

```
const Parent = () => {
  return ( 
    <Child className = {classNew1 classNew2}> 
      content 
    </Child>
  )
}
```

trying to get `<div class="basicClass classNew1 classNew2"></div>`

but I get - `<div class="basicClass undefined"></div>`

Tell me how to do it correctly?
Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to pass the classname of child component from its parent, right?

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but consider this utility, which helps a lot to manipulate classes in elements: https://github.com/lukeed/clsx

Comment: @Mario Vernari - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly since your Child component is expecting the prop named `newClasses` you should name it that in your parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  return ( 
    <Child newClasses = {"classNew1 classNew2"}> 
      content 
    </Child>
  )
}
```

This should fix your undefined issue

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Child = ({ className, children }) => {
  return <div className={className.join(' ')}>{children}</div>;
};

const Parent = () => {
  return <Child className={['classNew1', 'classNew2']}>content</Child>;
};
```